# Getting the profile ID of a Facebook user?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

This is different from the app ID, which is an ID associated with the app itself. How can I get the user's actual ID (or the profile ID)?

Comment: Why would you need the actual ID? All APIs accept the app scoped user ID.

Comment: App-scoped IDs were introduced, because having one global user ID across all apps, is a privacy risk (different app owners could easily consolidate their data they have about a user this way.) If there still was a way for you to get the global ID based on having an app-scoped ID, that measure would be pointless to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [/me](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/):

> The `/me` node is a special endpoint that translates to the `user_id`
> of the person (or the page_id of the Facebook Page) whose access token
> is currently being used to make the API calls.

```
curl -i -X GET \
 "https://graph.facebook.com/v9.0/me?access_token=<token>"
```

Will return

```
{
  "name": "<name>",
  "id": "<id>"
}
```

Comment: this just returns the app scoped id, not the real id - it is not possible to get the real id

Comment: Could the [Page-Scoped ID API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/pages/support/psid-api) may help you

Comment: the page scoped id is - as the app scope id - a scoped id and not the real user id. i assume he wants the real user id, but that one is not neccessary anyway. you can just use the scoped ids instead.